# Angular/Meteor routing issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, routes, angular-meteor

I'm trying the angular meteor whatsapp tutorial and I think I have a routing issue.

It's weird because I've followed every single step of the tuto.

The error is the following: nothing shows up in the browser. When I open the console, I have no error. The app is not crashing, otherwise I would have a crashing message in the browser. The path in the browser shows the one from `this.$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('tab/chats');`. In the browser it looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/#/tab/chats`.

**Routes.js**

```
import { Config } from 'angular-ecmascript/module-helpers';

import chatsTemplateUrl from '../templates/chats.html';
import tabsTemplateUrl from '../templates/tabs.html';

export default class RoutesConfig extends Config {
  configure() {
    this.$stateProvider
      .state('tab', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: tabsTemplateUrl
      })
      .state('tab.chats', {
        url: '/chats',
        views: {
          'tab-chats': {
            templateUrl: chatsTemplateUrl,
            controller: 'ChatsCtrl as chats'
          }
        }
      });

    this.$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('tab/chats');
  }
}

RoutesConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
```

**App.js**

```
// Libs
import 'angular-animate';
import 'angular-meteor';
import 'angular-sanitize';
import 'angular-ui-router';
import 'ionic-scripts';
import Angular from 'angular';
import Loader from 'angular-ecmascript/module-loader';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

// Modules
import RoutesConfig from '../routes';
import ChatsCtrl from '../controllers/chats.controller';
import CalendarFilter from '..filters/calendar.filter';

const App = 'Whatsapp';

// App
Angular.module(App, [
  'angular-meteor',
  'ionic'
]);

new Loader(App)
  .load(ChatsCtrl)
  .load(CalendarFilter)
  .load(RoutesConfig);

// Startup
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
  Angular.element(document).on('deviceready', onReady);
}
else {
  Angular.element(document).ready(onReady);
}

function onReady() {
  Angular.bootstrap(document, [App]);
}
```

I've installed every dependency or package needed for the app. I don't understand why I have this error.

Thanks, have a good day :)

Comment: Can you share the project as a repo?

Comment: Hi @Mikkel : https://github.com/justinedps26/messenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

You were missing angular-meteor-auth

Fixed with

```
meteor npm install --save angular-meteor-auth
```

Then in the browser console I see this:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../controller/new-chat.controller'
```

The file doesn't exist, I fixed it, but you have a bunch of other mistakes there - I'll let you take it from here

Comment: where have you fixed it?

Comment: I don't understand... The file does exist

Comment: The file doesn't exist you have the directory name wrong

Comment: And there are several other come name and directory mistakes.  The chrome console will tell you where the errors are

Comment: hum... I don't understand. I have a scripts directory inside client. Then i have a controller directory with new-chat.controller.js inside. What's wrong? I've never used angular with meteor, can you tell me what i've missed? :) And, actually, I can't see anything from the very beginning, maybe that's an ionic issue?

Comment: I fixed some issues and now i have this error message: `Failed to instantiate module Messenger due to`. I don't know how to solve the problem with angular-meteor

Comment: FIXED :))) Thanks for your help

Comment: No problems, could  you mark my answer as correct please?

Comment: Done :) Just one thing, the sms verification doesn't work, i don't receive any code on my phone. Is that normal?

Comment: What sms verification? Do you mean push notification?

Comment: I meant to log in the app but problem solved. I want to go further with this app and i'd like to add a bot to answer the message i send to user to test the app. How can i build a simple bot with meteor for that? No need for a particular answer, but maybe relevant websites where i can find something interesting :)

Comment: @JustineDupuis I would have a look at hubot and rocketchat's hubot integration. It would be worth asking a question about it, as I'm sure there are plenty of people interested in them, check out the hubot and bots tags on SO

Comment: Thank you @Mikkel ! Sorry for the late reply